# Cross master-branch merging?

Tags: git, version-control

People who have been working on the project I recently joined had two clones of the master branch on the remote repository. Now, I have to merge the newer one into the older one. This appears to me to be different form cross-branch merging. I thought cherry-picking changes might be the wrong way to go. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Could you please give more details and context about what is the problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Cupcake - What I am going to do is, I want all changes in the original branch despite the divergent developments. So , essentially, merging the two master branches.

Comment: @DonQuixote What do you mean two master branches?  You can't have two branches with the same name so I'm not sure what you mean.  In git the `master` branch is not special in any way other than it's the default name.  Merging two branches is always just merging two branches regardless of their names.

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't have a master-slave concept, so you don't need to do anything special

`git pull <remote-server> <remote-branch-name>`

That will get the data and do the merge.